# Problem with connection between custom application and qpidd compiled on ArchLinux while running them on Debian

Tags: debian, networking, arch-linux, tcp, c++

I have a custom application and **qpidd** (Qpid version 1.36) which had been built on **ArchLinux**. Default TCP with default settings is used as protocol to connect to the running qpidd, and the connection is established without any problem every time on **ArchLinux**. But I needed to test them on Debian. For this I copied all the necessary low-level-related .so files (ld-linux-x86-64, libc, libm, libgcc_s, etc.) and other .so files (including **Qpid**-related) to a PC with **Debian**. Of course, I put them in a directory set in the RPATH of both applications and so on. But on this distro I see the next message from **qpidd**:

`[Broker] warning Client closed connection with 501: No mutually acceptable authentication mechanism`

A little bit different message can be received from my application. In other words, connection cannot be established.

Why does this happen and how can it be solved?

Comment: How did you establish the set of "necessary low-level-related .so files"? Maybe there are configuration files which are not .so files but are read. Maybe there are dynamically loaded libraries ("plugins") that you missed? Have you considered installing qpidd on debian from the package manager rather than copying stuff from Arch?

Comment: I had established the set using dependance lists from linker (ldd) and looking at runtime results. Maybe, I did not copy some network-related libraries.
I decided to use all the stuff from ArchLinux because the application and other tools should be able to run on any distro, and not all of them can have all the packages needed.

Comment: ldd (a tool you should never use on other peoples code for security reasons) tells you about the libraries listed in the ELF headers (specifically DT_NEEDED entries). This is the stuff set up by the run time linker **before** the program is run. It does not cover libraries loaded dynamically by the program itself, which are frequently called plugins. It is not clear what you mean by "testing" on a debian system, you appear to be copying over much of Arch so it is not really a debian system.

Comment: @icarus, by "testing" I mean trying to run a program and looking after it's behaviour during runtime. So, do you recommend not to ship my applications with all the libraries? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Options include shipping a cut down Arch distribution as a docker or podman container, and snap and flatpak.